# spark exception in filter function

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, key-value, rdd

i have a PairRDD, its tuples are like

```
Tuple2<Integer, JavaPairRDD<String, String>>
```

i try to filter it but i get this error

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

i tried with the following code

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,JavaPairRDD<String,String>> lookup = lookups.filter(new filtrerRDD(num));
```

the function  filtrerRDD:

```
public static class filtrerRDD implements Function<Tuple2<Integer,JavaPairRDD<String,String> >,Boolean>{
    int num;
    public filtrer(int num){this.num=num;}

    @Override
    public Boolean call(Tuple2<Integer, JavaPairRDD<String, String>> t) throws Exception {
        Integer y=t._1();
        return (y==num);
    }

}
```

so what i am trying to do, is that i give a number "num" to the function and i try to get a subRDD that contains only tuples which their key is equal to "num", but i keep getting that error even that i don't use an other transormation or action inside filtrerRDD.

now i give you an example, for example i have the following RDD:

```
lookups={(1,pairRDD1)(9,pairRDD2)(5,pairRDD3)(6,pairRDD4)(5,pairRDD5)...}
```

and i give num=5, so the result RDD that i want is:

```
lookup={(5,pairRDD3)(5,pairRDD5)...}
```

Comment: Just looking at the type of the RDD (`JavaPairRDD<Integer,JavaPairRDD<String,String>>`) and exception you should realize this simply cannot work in Spark.

Comment: no, before using filter i tested it and it worked normally

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spark-users/_Efj40upvx4/BseCdgSbr_kJ - is that enough to convince you?

Comment: @zero323 thank you for convincing me, i was  just confused bcz i tested it as i said and it works normally, but i get that error just when i used filter , anyway thank you very much

Comment: @zero323 just a question please, if i try to change the type of the RDD for exapmle, JavaPairRDD<Integer,Tuple2<String,String>>, is the syntaxe that i used correct?

Comment: At the first glance it looks OK.